# What does the # (hash) mean in this type name?

Tags: c#, .net, powershell

I can only understand the type as far as `SoftwareIdentity`. I'm not sure what `SoftwareIdentity#GetPackage` signifies.

```
Get-Package | Get-Member | Select-Object -Property TypeName -Unique
 
TypeName
--------
Microsoft.PackageManagement.Packaging.SoftwareIdentity#GetPackage
```

Comment: What's the context? How can this be reproduced? The question is very unclear.

Comment: `Get-Package | Get-Member | Select-Object -Property TypeName -Unique` is PowerShell. But ultimately I'm asking what the (class?) relationship between 'SoftwareIdentity' and 'GetPackage' is in .NET. I thought '#' was meaningful in a type name.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, `Microsoft.PackageManagement.Packaging.SoftwareIdentity#GetPackage` is just the fully-qualified type name for the **GetPackage** public class (used by the `Get-Package` cmdlet) within Microsoft's `PackageManagement` module: [reference 1](https://github.com/OneGet/oneget/blob/08ae6e82df2230a601ed09191b26712b213afbc5/src/Microsoft.PowerShell.PackageManagement/Cmdlets/GetPackage.cs#L28)

The default display view defined for **GetPackage** provides `Name`, `Version`, `Source`, and `ProviderName` properties: [reference 2](https://github.com/OneGet/oneget/blob/08ae6e82df2230a601ed09191b26712b213afbc5/src/Microsoft.PowerShell.PackageManagement/PackageManagement.format.ps1xml#L62).  This view definition can be seen in-use for the display output of [Example 1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/PackageManagement/Get-Package?view=powershell-7.1#example-1--get-all-installed-packages) of the `Get-Package` cmdlet.

The `Get-Package` cmdlet returns an array of `SoftwareIdentity` objects: [reference 3](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/PackageManagement/Get-Package?view=powershell-7.1#outputs), explaining part of the TypeName used.

Historically, using WMI as a back-drop, Microsoft might expose type names using this format to separate wrapper classes vs. underlying namespaces and class names of an object -- which you may discover in other WMI-based coding efforts.

Comment: This is helpful. But I made the assumption that # was an operator like '.' and that 'SoftwareIdentity#GetPackage' defined a relationship just like ParentClass.ChildClass or [Type]::StaticMethod() does where '.' and '::' would serve similarly to '#'. I thought it was more than an arbitrary declaration somewhere.